# Routing in fat free framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, fat-free-framework

I have started learning fat free framework, after installing it, when I wrote

```
require __DIR__.'/lib/base.php';
F3::set('DEBUG',3);
F3::set('UI','ui/');
F3::route('GET /',function () {echo "hello";});
F3::run();
```

in index.php it displayed hello on screen, but when I add this to above

```
F3::route('GET /about', function () {echo "hello";});
```

and when I opened localhost/freefat-master/about then page not found appears on the screen. following are the details of my .htaccess file

```
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.ini$
RewriteRule \.ini$ - [R=404]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

i have already tried changing RewriteRule to /fatfree/index.php. Please suggest me something. i am using linux,mysql and apache.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change anything in your `.htaccess` except for the `RewriteBase` line. Just change it to

`RewriteBase /fatfree-master/`

and it should work.

Comment: still not working. please suggest me something i am stucked here

Comment: Is mod_rewrite even installed on your server and is it activated?

Comment: No i dont know about that, please tell me the required steps

Comment: I have checked using sudo a2enmod rewrite and it says module rewrite already enabled.

Comment: Umm, I also forgot to mention, that you have to remove the `#` in in front of the first line of the .htaccess. The # is a comment and will disable that line.

Comment: Could you please post your current .htaccess somewhere? Eventually your first post?

Comment: RewriteBase /fatfree/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.ini$
RewriteRule \.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

Comment: You did not, what I wrote in my answer ... Please use `RewriteBase /fatfree-master/` if that's the folder you extracted F3 to.

Comment: I want to add that when i run index.php and it opens correctly but i have no folder named cache and temp in my fatfree-master folder

Comment: Then create them or fix your folder permission to allow F3 to create them by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually trying to open

```
localhost/freefat-master/about
```

you better make sure that is the actual path. Usually it's called

```
localhost/fatfree-master/about
```

Obviously you might have changed this.

Comment: actualy I have wriiten localhost/fatfree-master/about, but that too is not working

Comment: What do you mean with "you have written?" Did you use the url you have written in your .htaccess?

Comment: Can you try to copy the URL that works in to your question? If the first route works, the second should too.

Comment: I have used path localhost/fatfree-master/about, but this is not working,

Comment: I don't think your URL matches what you have in .htaccess - in the comment above you have written /fatfree/ in rewritebase, but you try to access fatfree-master. You wrote originally that the the first example worked - what was the URL that worked?

Answer (score 0):

Just added a new parameter 'SERVERNAME' in /etc/apache2/000-default and it worked, thanks to all the repliers.